# Why does Spanish tend to swap letters in words?

Tags: language-change, spanish, metathesis

I can't remember the source, but I recall hearing that Spanish (my native tongue) tends to swap letters in words (accidentally). Examples

- Latin *diabolo* becomes *diablo(o)*. (perhaps this is a non-example, and it is losing an 'o' instead.)
- French *guirlande* becomes *guirnalda*.
- Ukrainian *Ukraina* (Україна) becomes *Ucrania*.

  1. Does this phenomenon have a name?
  2. Why does it happen in Spanish?
  3. Is it common throughout (romance?) languages or specific to Spanish?

Comment: It seems the answer is [metathesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metathesis_(linguistics)).

Comment: Yes, and you're right that first example is probably deletion of the first /o/ instead. Notice that this has nothing to do with letters; these are phenomena of spoken language, where people switch or change sounds, not letters (you hear this all the time if you pay attention), and the writing is just following how people speak. All languages do things like metathesis and deletion (cf. English brid → bird, hros→horse). It is not clear to me if Spanish is especially prone to this sound change or why, though from Latin to Spanish specifically there are some widespread, regular metatheses.

Comment: For another example that has bothered me for years, consider "Dinamarca".

Comment: Also "crocodile" becomes "cocodrilo"! (edit: and now I read the first answer I see it uses that example :(

Comment: Close. Lack of research.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Metathesis is common across languages, including in the varieties of Romance that emerged from Vulgar Latin. However, Western Romance had it more than Eastern Romance; within Western Romance, Iberian Romance appears to have had it more than Gallo-Romance.

**Consonant clusters involving a dental and /n/ and /l/**

In Western Romance, many new clusters of /tn/ were formed from the loss of a vowel. For example: Classical Latin `retineō` > Vulgar Latin `*retina` underwent intervocalic voicing to form `*/ˈrɛdina/`, preserved in Italian as *redine*. But the unstressed vowel in the middle was lost in Western Romance, giving `*/ˈrɛdna/` which led to different outcomes:

> Metathesis: Spanish *rienda*, Galician *renda*
>
> Lenition > Assimilation: French *resne* > *rêne*, from which English *rein*
>
> Dissimilation: Catalan *regna*

Another good example: descendants of Latin `spatula`:

> Assimilation /t/ to /l/: Italian *spalla*, Sicilian *spadda*; also Friulian *spale*, Walloon *spale*, Venetian *spała*, and French *espalle* > *espaule* > *épaule*
>
> Dissimilation of the /l/: Catalan *espatlla*
>
> Metathesis: Spanish *espalda*, Portuguese *espalda*
>
> *preserved*: Romansch *spatla*, Occitan *espatla*

**Metathesis between /r/ and /l/**

These two sounds are traditionally classified as "liquids", and they commonly underwent metathesis in both directions.

The renowned example of Old French *crocodile ~ cocodril* actually dates from medieval Latin `crocodīlus` vs `cocodrillus`, and modern languages probably fell on one side or the other in the early modern period. These are probably "semi-learned" borrowings rather than being fully inherited.

Nonetheless, semi-learned but genuine examples such as Latin `miraculum` > Spanish *milagro*, Galician and Portuguese *milagre*; `periculum` > Spanish *peligro*, Asturian and Leonese *peligru* (metathesis didn't happen in Galician and Portuguese *perigo*) testify to how common it was.

**Glide metathesis**

This surfaces as changes in the vowel in the modern language, and is common to much of Western Romance. It is most obvious with Latin /sj/ and /rj/ glides. For example, for Latin `caseus`, [resulted](https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/3247205.pdf) in Spanish and Aragonese *queso*, Galician *queixo*, Portuguese *queijo*, Leonese *queisu*, but Sardinian *casu*, Neapolitan *caso*, Sicilian *caciu*, Italian *cacio*, Romanian *caș*.

In this case, Portuguese [goes further](https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/3247205.pdf) than Spanish, as metathesis seems to have happened with Latin words with /pj/ and /bj/, e.g. Latin `apiu` led to Spanish and Galician *apio* but Portuguese *aipo*, Latin `rabia` led to Spanish and Galician *rabia* but Portuguese *raiva*.

**Stronger metathesis in Old Spanish**

There were quite a few more examples in Old Spanish, especially in [certain future tense conjugations](https://online.liverpooluniversitypress.co.uk/doi/abs/10.3828/bhs.2014.35) (such as the regular *tenré* and after metathesis *terné*, as well as the version *tendré* with consonant insertion which is the modern standard form). In summary, from an optimality perspective, a rising sonority across the syllable boundary led to a lot of metathesis, in a tendency to preserve the usual "sonority cycle" that makes up a syllable.

This also [included](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.575.1779&rep=rep1&type=pdf) the second person plural imperatives with enclitic object pronouns, e.g. *decid + lo* making *decildo* as well as the regular *decidlo*. The article says that this became non-productive by the 17th century, as the `ALIGN` constraint moved above the markedness constraint `SYLLABLE CONTRAST`.

Comment: This is really helpful! But what do you mean that "tiendré" is the modern form? The modern form is "tendré" (1st personal singular future simple?). Perhaps I am confused as to what "modern" means?

Comment: Eek typo plus unclear wording - I'll edit. _Tendré_ is the modern "standard" form

Answer (score 7):

The modern language Spanish does not have a significant "tendency" to moving segments (a process known as metathesis), but there are some historical cases of metathesis going historically from Latin or other older language stages to some branch of Romance (branches leading to Spanish). Some examples are caseo > queso 'cheese', catēnātum > candado 'padlock', parabola > palabra 'word', spatula > espalda 'back', oblitare > olvidar 'forget'. In modern Spanish, the verb 'forget' is simply learned as /olvid(a)/ and there is no metathesis.

This is not a regular sound change (compare the change of earlier [ʒ] to [x] spelled *j*): it sporadically affects some words but not others. It is found in other Romance languages (berbex > brebis 'sheep', formaticus > fromage 'cheese', mosquito (Spanish) > moustique. Very many languages in the world have this as a sporadic historical change. A few have it as a actual rules in the grammar (Faroese, Klallam), and many more have been said to have it but investigation of the details indicates that most cases are two separate processes. The question of *why* this happens is vexing, but it generally seems to be related to changes in syllable structure. For instance, the earlier form *espadla* runs counter to the emerging tendency to not have obstruents in the coda.

Cases like caseo > kasʲo > kaiso > keso, also found historically in Ancient Greek, seem involve intermediate palatalized consonants and perceptual "leftward attraction" of the palalization to the onset of the consonant (this is a variable in palatalized consonants across languages: sometimes they are not evidence on the preceding vowel, sometimes they are).

Liquid metathesis (*palabra*) seems to have a different explanation. It seems that it is generally difficult to acoustically parse and localize two liquids (r,l) in a word, so what people can get is that there are two of them, but it's hard to perceive what order they appear in. Thus r...l and l...r "metathesis" is also common across languages. So there are a number of explanations, depending on the particular case.